# How to unlock Linux Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: updates, users, unlock

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Recently (about 7 months ago) I got a notification about installing a new update. I ignored it for a while until I decided I would go through with it. 
It led me through a series of questions and all sorts of setups which I should've followed more carefully.

After installing, I couldn't unlock my account and I have been stuck since with a Guest Account.

Even when I try to Unlock it, when I click on the button "Unlock" in the upper right corner - nothing happens. Like clicking on an empty space on the desktop.

I haven't used my laptop much because I didn't have any work to do on it. Now that I have, I need to FIX it. ASAP.

I don't have and can't add any account - neither Standard or Administrative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: Thank you, but no...

Comment: sudo: unable to change to root gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: How exactly did attempting to reset your password from the recovery session fail? Your description is limited, so we cannot tell if there is a serious problem with your system, or if you just made a typo. The more you can tell us, the more we can help you.

Comment: I'm too stupid for this. I'll just pay someone to fix my laptop... Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: It's easier and cheaper to backup your data and reinstall than to pay someone (who will just do that anyway)

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll just instal Windows 10, I am too used to Windows.